# "Также" и "так же".

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно, также

Никак не пойму, когда пишется "также", а когда раздельно. В каком смысле идут эти два написания? Возможно ли разделить их, по задаваемым вопросам?

Answer (score 2):

Я не возражаю по сути предыдущих ответов. Только есть соображение, что сложности возникают обычно совсем не в тех примерах... Если перед "то же" идет предлог, то это всегда раpдельно, т.к. перед наречием (или союзом [1]) "тоже" подобный предлог просто невозможен. Захочешь - слитно не напишешь. 
А реальная проблема может возникнуть как раз с фразами типа "Я так()же думаю": 
*a) "Я думаю, что ЖИ-ШИ пишется с буквой И" - "Я то же [самое] думаю"="Я [точно] так же думаю". 

б) "Я думаю, почему ЖИ-ШИ пишется с буквой И" - "Я тоже думаю [об этом]"="Я также думаю  [о том же]".* 
Идея о проверке заменой одного на другое ("тоже" на "также" или наоборот) здесь не проходит. 
Но самое интересное, что в принципе ответы б) годятся и для а).  
Приходится ориентироваться по смыслу.  
Короче, лучше проверять дважды, по обоим названным правилам: взаимной заменой и отбрасыванием частицы "же".

Более академическое (не академичное, заметьте!) правило есть у Розенталя:
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/37.htm

А от себя лично рискну предложить проверку заменой "то()же" на "это же". Если эта замена проходит не только грамматически, но и без заметного изменения смысла, то смело пишите раздельно. Правило, насколько понимаю, универсально.

[1] Я не хочу здесь дискутировать на тему "*тоже* - это союз, наречие или частица". Во всяком случае трактовка *тоже* как наречия вполне допустима как минимум в некоторых случаях.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы запомнить провописание ТАКЖЕ/ТАК ЖЕ, надо вспомнить, что есть в рус. яз  синонимичные союзы ТАКЖЕ И ТОЖЕ, которые пишутся слитно. Они легко заменяют друг друга. Это свойство можно использовать для проверки. Н-р: Я тоже/также так думаю.  Если же такая замена невозможна, то перед нами не союзы, а сочетания указательного местоимения ТО или ТАК с частицей ЖЕ, которые пишутся отдельно. Частицу ЖЕ в таком случае часто можно просто опустить, при этом смысл предложений не изменяется  . Сравните: В ТО ЖЕ время он пристально смотрел в книгу. Читателей осталось ТАК ЖЕ мало, как нас.

Comment: Я так()же думаю?

Comment: Проверка знаний??? Я также думаю - Я так же думаю. Комментарии излишни.

Answer (score 1):

Частицу ЖЕ  можно  опустить или переставить, при этом смысл предложений не изменяется и остаётся понятным.